# Catch timeout error when using ngrx in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to handle Timeout error when effect make an Http Request.

Here's my effect

```
loadSchedulings$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDate),
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.apiCallsService.getSchedulings().pipe(
        map(trips => ({ type: ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDateSuccess, payload: trips })),
        catchError(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return EMPTY;
        })
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Here's my `getSchedulingService`

```
getSchedulings() {
  return this.http.get<ISchedules>(this.urlData).pipe(
    map(data => {
      ...
      return groupByDate;
    }),
    timeout(2500),
    catchError(error => of(`Request timed out`))
  );
}
```

Actually no error is catched by `catchError` inside my effect , however I send error inside my service function.

How to do that using rxjs operators ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see this is that you are going to catch the error in your getSchedulings() call and you never propagate this error, instead you return a new observable of it. try replacing the of with a throwError:

```
    catchError(error => throwError(`Request timed out`))
```

which will then in turn be handled by your effect